# Handle Paging with RxJava

Tags: android, pagination, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit + RxJava on an Android app and am asking myself about how to handle the API pagination to chain calls until all data is being retrieved. Is something like this:

```
Observable<ApiResponse> getResults(@Query("page") int page);
```

The *ApiResponse* object has a simple structure:

```
class ApiResponse {
    int current;
    Integer next;
    List<ResponseObject> results;
}
```

The API will return a **next** value until is last page.

There's some good way to achieve this? Tried to combine some *flatMaps()*, but had no success.

Comment: Could you clarify your input and your output? A method signature with its description would be better.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could model it recursively:

```
Observable<ApiResponse> getPageAndNext(int page) {
  return getResults(page)
      .concatMap(new Func1<ApiResponse, Observable<ApiResponse>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<ApiResponse> call(ApiResponse response) {
          // Terminal case.
          if (response.next == null) {
            return Observable.just(response);
          }
          return Observable.just(response)
              .concatWith(getPageAndNext(response.next));
        }

      });
}
```

Then, to consume it,

```
getPageAndNext(0)
    .concatMap(new Func1<ApiResponse, Observable<ResponseObject>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<ResponseObject> call(ApiResponse response) {
          return Observable.from(response.results);
        }

    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<ResponseObject>() { /** Do something with it */ });
```

That should get you a stream of `ResponseObject` that will arrive in order, and most likely arrive in page-size chunks.

Comment: Every day I discover a new RxJava operator (concatMap is new for me). Tested and approved :)

Comment: In this example, is there a way to wait for all the results to come in and then combine the results into a single response that you can subscribe to?

Comment: `toList` is probably the easiest, which will emit a single list of all elements once the `Observable` completes. there are a few other operators for grouping into collections as well, such as `reduce`.

Comment: To answer my own question, you can use **toList()** which conveniently returns a List of all the emitted responses.

Comment: Note that I refined this a bit in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29594194/1424355 for handling cases where recursion may blow the stack. Also, it may just be a simpler alternative in general.

Comment: "where recursion may blow the stack" and it blows. @lopar I really appreciate your solution, but could you add info that this solution causes serious memory leak? It would be great if you add a link to you another answer, because I didn't notice your last comment in the first place.

Comment: i am getting stack overflow error.Is there any work around for this?

Comment: @lopar is there any reason why you use `concatMap`  in the consumer?

Comment: As noted by other commenters, this does throw a StackOverflow exception in some cases. There's no work around for this unless you completely change the implementation of this function to use a loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 3):

[Iopar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1424355/lopar) gave a great example.

Just a small addition.
If you want to get all pages in one onNext() call.
It can be helpful when you want to **zip** this result with one more Observable.
You should write:

```
private List<String> list = new LinkedList() {
    {
        add("a");
        add("b");
        add("c");
    }
};

int count = 1;

public Observable<List<String>> getAllStrings(int c) {
    return Observable.just(list)
            .concatMap(
                    strings -> {
                        if (c == 3) {
                            return Observable.just(list);
                        } else {
                            count += 1;
                            return Observable.zip(
                                    Observable.just(list),
                                    getAllStrings(count),
                                    (strings1, strings2) -> {
                                        strings1.addAll(strings2);
                                        return strings1;
                                    }
                            );
                        }
                    }
            );
}
```

**Usages**:

```
getAllStrings(0)
        .subscribe(strings -> {
            Log.w(TAG, "call: " + strings);
        });
```

and you will get:

```
call: [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've answered my solution in a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34378263/143733

The trick or amendment to the solution provided by @Iopar is the inclusion of a 'trigger' Observable that can be emitted by a variety of ways.

In the code I posted, it is emitted once a full page of elements have been processed however it could also occur based on a user clicking a button/scrolling.