# RxSwift - Fetch undetermined resources via HTTP

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have undetermined resources that need to be fetched from a server. I tried to accomplish this by using the `repeatElement()` and `concat()` operators like this:

```
repeatElement(0, CurrentThreadScheduler.instance).map({ _ -> Observable<[Task]> in
    // API.getTasks() uses Alamofire to request data
    return API.getTasks(loggedUser, after: loggedUser.taskPullTime)
}).concat().takeWhile({ (tasks) -> Bool in
    return tasks.count > 0
})
```

Unfortunately, `repeatElement` will just emit an item without waiting for the old one to be handled. I think the reason is that Alamorfire executes in a private serial queue.
However, I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

I used the strategy inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594194/2408447) in my Android project. Everything works fine because Retrofit init HTTP request in a synchronous manner.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @wint checkout [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/315)

Comment: Thank you, I've done that already but I think there should be a simpler way. It is very simple in RxJava. :)

Comment: My workaround is making the request for this sequence become synchronous, using USLSession.