# RxJava2 & Retrofit: How to get pages of data

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

**Goal:** I want to repeatedly call a Retrofit service (GET) that returns paged data, until I've exhausted its pages. Going from page 0 to page n.

First, I've looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047272/handle-paging-with-rxjava) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444297/stack-overflow-when-using-retrofit-rxjava-concatwith/29594194#29594194) answers already. The first actually works, but I'm not overly fond of the recursive solution as it could lead to stack overflow. The second fails the moment you try to use a scheduler.

Here's a sample of the second:

```
Observable.range(0, 5/*Integer.MAX_VALUE*/) // generates page values
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())           // need this to prevent UI hanging
    // gamesService uses Schedulers.io() by default
    .flatMapSingle { page -> gamesService.getGames(page) }
    .takeWhile { games -> games.isNotEmpty() } // games is a List<Game>
    .subscribe(
        { games -> db.insertAll(games) },
        { Logger.e(TAG, it, "Error getting daily games: ${it.message}") }
    )
```

What I *expect* this to do is stop the moment that `gamesService.getGames(page)` returns an empty list. Instead, it continues hitting the endpoint for an indeterminate number of times, with incrementing page values. I have experimented a bit in unit tests with `Single.just(intVal)` and determined that the problem appears to be the fact that my service is automatically subscribed on `Schedulers.io()`. This is how I define my Retrofit services:

```
private inline fun <reified T> createService(okClient: OkHttpClient): T {
    val rxAdapter = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(config.apiEndpoint.endpoint())
        .client(okClient)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
        .addConverterFactory(moshiConverterFactory())
        .build()

    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

It's really not an option to *not* use `createWithScheduler()` here.

Here's another idea I tried:

```
val atomic = AtomicInteger(0)
Observable.generate<Int> { it.onNext(atomic.getAndIncrement()) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapSingle { page -> gamesService.getGames(page) }
    .takeWhile { games -> games.isNotEmpty() }
    .subscribe(
        { games -> dailyGamesDao.insertAll(games) },
        { Logger.e(TAG, it, "Error getting daily games: ${it.message}") }
    )
```

This is another case where it worked as expected right up until I introduced a `Scheduler`. The generator generates *way* too many values, when I'm expecting it to stop when the `takeWhile` discovers an empty list.

I've also tried various kinds of `concat` (concatWith, concatMap, etc).

At this point, I'm really just looking for someone to help me correct the obvious (to them) and completely basic misunderstanding I clearly have with RxJava operators.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a partial solution. (I may edit this answer later if and when I find my "final" solution.)

**tl;dr** I should convert my `Single`s to `Observable`s and use the `flatMap` overload that takes a `maxConcurrency` parameter. For example:

```
Observable.range(0, SOME_SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_NUMBER)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap({ page -> gamesService.getGames(page).toObservable }, 1 /* maxConcurrency */)
    .takeWhile { games -> games.isNotEmpty() }
    .subscribe(
        { games -> dailyGamesDao.insertAll(games) },
        { Logger.e(TAG, it, "Error getting daily games: ${it.message}") }
    )
```

That basically does it. By limiting the number of concurrent threads to 1, I now have the "one after the other" behavior I was seeking. The only thing I don't like about this, and I suppose it's a minor gripe, is that my base `Observable.range()` can still emit a *lot* of values -- way more than ever get used by the downstream `Single`s/`Observable`s.

PS: One reason I couldn't find this solution earlier is I was using RxJava 2.1.9. When I pushed it to 2.1.14, I had access to the new overloads. Oh well.