# Paginate Observable results without recursion - RxJava

Tags: java, pagination, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable

I've got a pretty standard API pagination problem which you can handle with some simple recursion. Here's a fabricated example:

```
public Observable<List<Result>> scan() {
    return scanPage(Optional.empty(), ImmutableList.of());
}

private Observable<?> scanPage(Optional<KEY> startKey, List<Result> results) {
    return this.scanner.scan(startKey, LIMIT)
            .flatMap(page -> {
                if (!page.getLastKey().isPresent()) {
                    return Observable.just(results);
                }
                return scanPage(page.getLastKey(), ImmutableList.<Result>builder()
                        .addAll(results)
                        .addAll(page.getResults())
                        .build()
                );
            });
}
```

But this can obviously create a massive callstack. How can I do this imperatively but maintain the Observable stream?

Here's an imperative blocking example:

```
public List<Result> scan() {
    Optional<String> startKey = Optional.empty();
    final ImmutableList.Builder<Result> results = ImmutableList.builder();

    do {
        final Page page = this.scanner.scan(startKey);
        startKey = page.getLastKey();
        results.addAll(page.getResults());
    } while (startKey.isPresent());

    return results.build();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is true that recursive observables create a massive callstack. `scanPage` returns before the next `scanPage` is called, so the calls are sequential, but not nested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the most elegant of solutions but you can use subjects and side-effects. See the toy example below

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import rx.subjects.*;

public class Pagination {
    static HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> pages = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        pages.put("default", new ArrayList<String>());
        pages.put("2", new ArrayList<String>());
        pages.put("3", new ArrayList<String>());
        pages.put("4", new ArrayList<String>());

        pages.get("default").add("2");
        pages.get("default").add("Maths");
        pages.get("default").add("Chemistry");  

        pages.get("2").add("3");
        pages.get("2").add("Physics");   
        pages.get("2").add("Biology"); 

        pages.get("3").add("4");
        pages.get("3").add("Art");   

        pages.get("4").add("");
        pages.get("4").add("Geography"); 



        Observable<List<String>> ret = Observable.defer(() -> 
        { 
            System.out.println("Building Observable");
            ReplaySubject<String> pagecontrol = ReplaySubject.<String>create(1);
            Observable<List<String>> ret2 = pagecontrol.asObservable().concatMap(aKey -> 
            {
                if (!aKey.equals("")) {
                    return Observable.just(pages.get(aKey)).doOnNext(page -> pagecontrol.onNext(page.get(0)));
                } else {
                    return Observable.<List<String>>empty().doOnCompleted(()->pagecontrol.onCompleted());
                }
            });
            pagecontrol.onNext("default");
            return ret2;
        });
        // Use this if you want to ensure work isn't done again
        ret = ret.cache();
        ret.subscribe(l -> System.out.println("Sub 1 : " + l));
        ret.subscribe(l -> System.out.println("Sub 2 : " + l));
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
    }
}
```

Edited with improvements.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't think that will work. The outcome will just be the first result of the scan as that will have been set, but the flow of the main execution thread will find that currentKey has not been set yet, and exit.

Comment: Looks like you're right. The problem is the key. If there's no regular way of generating it e.g. "1","2", etc. then I think you're stuck with the recursive solution which has its own issues if you have too many pages.

Comment: See the edited answer for a hacky solution using a subject and side-effects.

Comment: This is definitely closer. The problem I have with this is that I have to subscribe to the observable *before* I initiate it. It makes it difficult to return the Observable from the function. I guess the trick is to pass a subscriber in, rather than returning the stream. Unfortunately that's not how my code works ATM.

Comment: Edited with improvements. I think this should meet all your requirements. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 5):

JohnWowUs' answer is great and helped me understand how to avoid the recursion effectively, but there were some points I was still confused about, so I'm posting my tweaked version.

Summary:

- The individual pages are returned as a `Single`.
- Use a `Flowable` to stream each of the items contained in the pages. This means callers to our function do not need to know about the individual pages and can just collect the contained items.
- Use a `BehaviorProcessor` to start with the first page, and fetch each subsequent page once we have checked with the current page if the next page is available.
- The key is that the call to `processor.onNext(int)` starts the next iteration.

This code depends on [rxjava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.1.9) and [reactive-streams](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.2).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.processors.BehaviorProcessor;

public class Pagination {

    // Fetch all pages and return the items contained in those pages, using the provided page fetcher function
    public static <T> Flowable<T> fetchItems(Function<Integer, Single<Page<T>>> fetchPage) {
        // Processor issues page indices
        BehaviorProcessor<Integer> processor = BehaviorProcessor.createDefault(0);
        // When an index number is issued, fetch the corresponding page
        return processor.concatMap(index -> fetchPage.apply(index).toFlowable())
                        // when returning the page, update the processor to get the next page (or stop)
                        .doOnNext(page -> {
                            if (page.hasNext()) {
                                processor.onNext(page.getNextPageIndex());
                            } else {
                                processor.onComplete();
                            }
                        })
                        .concatMapIterable(Page::getElements);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fetchItems(Pagination::examplePageFetcher).subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    // A function to fetch a page of our paged data
    private static Single<Page<String>> examplePageFetcher(int index) {
        return Single.just(pages.get(index));
    }

    // Create some paged data
    private static ArrayList<Page<String>> pages = new ArrayList<>(3);

    static {
        pages.add(new Page<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two"), Optional.of(1)));
        pages.add(new Page<>(Arrays.asList("three", "four"), Optional.of(2)));
        pages.add(new Page<>(Arrays.asList("five"), Optional.empty()));
    }

    static class Page<T> {
        private List<T> elements;
        private Optional<Integer> nextPageIndex;

        public Page(List<T> elements, Optional<Integer> nextPageIndex) {
            this.elements = elements;
            this.nextPageIndex = nextPageIndex;
        }

        public List<T> getElements() {
            return elements;
        }

        public int getNextPageIndex() {
            return nextPageIndex.get();
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextPageIndex.isPresent();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works fin and is pretty simple. I have a few more question about this solution. See my post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772102/javarx-pagination-observe-in-each-interration-rather-than-at-the-end-generic

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use token stream: get data for initial token, push next token to stream once fresh remote data is obtained, and resubscribe until token is empty

```
 public Observable<Window> paging() {

        Subject<Token, Token> tokenStream = BehaviorSubject.<Token>create().toSerialized();

        tokenStream.onNext(Token.startToken());

        Observable<Window> dataStream =
                Observable.defer(() -> tokenStream.first().flatMap(this::remoteData))
                        .doOnNext(window -> tokenStream.onNext(window.getToken()))
                        .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.flatMap(__ -> tokenStream).takeWhile(Token::hasMore));

        return dataStream;
    }
```

The result is

```
Window{next token=Token{key='1'}, data='data for token: Token{key=''}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='2'}, data='data for token: Token{key='1'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='3'}, data='data for token: Token{key='2'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='4'}, data='data for token: Token{key='3'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='5'}, data='data for token: Token{key='4'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='6'}, data='data for token: Token{key='5'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='7'}, data='data for token: Token{key='6'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='8'}, data='data for token: Token{key='7'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='9'}, data='data for token: Token{key='8'}'}
Window{next token=Token{key='10'}, data='data for token: Token{key='9'}'}
```

Copy pastable sample

```
public class RxPaging {

    public Observable<Window> paging() {

        Subject<Token, Token> tokenStream = BehaviorSubject.<Token>create().toSerialized();

        tokenStream.onNext(Token.startToken());

        Observable<Window> dataStream =
                Observable.defer(() -> tokenStream.first().flatMap(this::remoteData))
                        .doOnNext(window -> tokenStream.onNext(window.getToken()))
                        .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.flatMap(__ -> tokenStream).takeWhile(Token::hasMore));

        return dataStream;
    }

    private Observable<Window> remoteData(Token token) {
        /*limit number of pages*/
        int page = page(token);
        Token nextToken = page < 10
                ? nextPageToken(token)
                : Token.endToken();

        return Observable
                .just(new Window(nextToken, "data for token: " + token))
                .delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private int page(Token token) {
        String key = token.getKey();
        return key.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(key);
    }

    private Token nextPageToken(Token token) {
        String tokenKey = token.getKey();
        return tokenKey.isEmpty() ? new Token("1") : nextToken(tokenKey);
    }

    private Token nextToken(String tokenKey) {
        return new Token(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tokenKey) + 1));
    }

    public static class Token {
        private final String key;

        private Token(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public static Token endToken() {
            return startToken();
        }

        public static Token startToken() {
            return new Token("");
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public boolean hasMore() {
            return !key.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Token{" +
                    "key='" + key + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }


    public static class Window {
        private final Token token;
        private final String data;

        public Window(Token token, String data) {
            this.token = token;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Token getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Window{" +
                    "next token=" + token +
                    ", data='" + data + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPaging() throws Exception {
        paging().toBlocking().subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. I haven't tried implementing it but I wonder how it would compare to the use of a Subject in JohnWowUs' solution?

Comment: Both use helper token stream - difference is how data stream "round-robin" is aborted.  Regarding subject - in John's solution unbounded replay subject is used, which may or may not be a problem, depends on estimated pages count. It can be safely replaced by BehaviorSubject (i think he made a typo and used ReplaySubject.create(1) instead of ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1) - which is identical to BehaviorSubject)

Answer (score -3):

Just an idea, why wouldnt you implement your own iterable that iterates over your pages and then make an observer from it?

Example :

```
Observable.from(new Iterable<T>() {

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<T>() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return hasNextPage(currentPageKey);
                }

                @Override
                public T next() {

                    page = getNextPage(currentPageKey);
                    currentPageKey = page.getKey();
                    return page;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

a more elegant way would be to make your page manager (the scanner variable in your code example i believe) implement iterable and write the iteration logic there.

Comment: This doesn't work as you're just realising a synchronous Iterable and wrapping it in an Observable. In fact the issue is that the 'getNextPage' returns an Observable, so the Iterator would never actually know whether it 'hasNext'.