# Pagination in Java Reactive Programming

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am still new in Java Reactive Programming and my project Requirement wants me to implement Pagination with Reactive Programming in Java.

Like if I hit an API which returns me 10000 records in stream then I needs to return a flux with proper pagination.

Can anyone suggest me a good approach about this?

Like this is the approach that I am following.

Repository

```
  public interface CouchBaseRepository extends ReactiveCouchBaseRepository<Book,Integer> {
   @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where name=$1")
   public Flux<Book> getPaginatedFlux(String name ,final Pageable pageable);
```

This is my Repositorty but when I up my application then it shows this following error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice, interface java.util.List]
```

I cannot use Page inteface here as it is blocking so Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Just use `Flux.window`. The real question is why you need this? Reactive programming is about streaming and back pressure - pagination is a really coarse type of flowable pattern - why not just use the flow control built into the reactive pipeline?

Comment: It's a good practice to show large chunks of data in smaller chunks that's what pagination does. We have Pageable to implement pagination in spring but as you said if we use pagination then there will be blocking somehow. The real question is can we still benefit from pagination over this blocking cost.

Comment: You're not thinking reactively, you're thinking like a Spring developer. Take `Flux` of records straight from the database and return it to the user. There are no chunks, just an infinite back pressure aware stream of data.

Comment: [Paginate Observable results without recursion - RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326380/paginate-observable-results-without-recursion-rxjava/48580794#48580794)

Answer (score 7):

I haven't worked with spring-webflux yet, so I can't comment on specific API calls, but I'll provide a "theoretical" answer that might help as well.

Flux represents a stream of data (possibly infinite). So, pagination is kind of not consistent with reactivity, only because they're talking about different things

Consider implementing pagination with input parameters (like usual limit/offset) in the method that returns Flux of (logically decided) up to 10000 records as per your requirement.

So, one call will be handled in a "reactive manner" but it will return only one page of data, if you want to load another page - do another reactive call.

Of course at the level of streams, after 10000 objects receive, the stream should be closed.
This is the approach I suggest.

There is an another option: implement everything via one stream, but in this case the client side (UI or whatever that consumes the paged data) will have to be "smart enough" to load /unload only the required data. In other words, if all-in-all you have, say 1 million objects to show, think whether you should avoid situation where all 1 million is loaded on client side at once.

In addition the page navigation will be kind of tricky (stuff like, get next/previous page). I haven't worked like this before. I think bottom line, the choice will be requirement driven.

Comment: The trouble with pagination via input parameters is, as the call pages deeper, the database has to basically recreate the query and page through it to the right spot.  This gets slower and slower as the deeper pages of data are fetched, resulting in timeouts