# Android RXJava2 Retrofit Handling paging

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm having issues handling paging with RXJava2. I tried to follow this [post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047272/handle-paging-with-rxjava) but it was dated. I was hoping to get a more up to date answer. I'm using Retrofit and I'm trying to page a third party API till I have all of the results. The response is below but I pretty much want to through all pages and combine all results.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
public Observable<WatchList> syncWatchlistSection(String accountId) {
    String sessionToken = mLocal.getSessionId();
    int page = 1;

    return getWatchlistFromServerHelper(sessionToken, accountId, page).concatMap(new Function<WatchList, ObservableSource<? extends WatchList>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<? extends WatchList> apply(WatchList watchList) throws Exception {
            return Observable.fromArray(watchList);
        }
    });

}
```

And in the same file the helper file similar to the previous SO post.

```
private Observable<WatchList> getWatchlistFromServerHelper(String sessionToken, String accountId, int page) {
        return mRestAPI.fetchWatchlistOnServer(sessionToken, accountId, page).concatMap(new Function<WatchList, Observable<WatchList>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<WatchList> apply(WatchList watchList) throws Exception {
                if (watchList.getPage() == watchList.getTotalPages()) {
                    return Observable.just(watchList);
                }
                return Observable.just(watchList).concatWith(getWatchlistFromServerHelper(sessionToken, accountId, page + 1));
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm calling this via a subscribe on my activity.

```
mSectionLogic.syncWatchlistSection(String.valueOf(account.getId()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<WatchList>() {
              ... so on ...
```

This works but doesn't handle the paging. The response looks something like:

```
{
  page: 1,
  totalPages: 5,
  results: []
}
```

What I've done is it should return when `page == totalPages`. Except it doesn't combine the previous results and just returns the last page of results.

mRestAPI.fetchWatchlistOnServer is the Retrofit2 Get request that returns `Observable<Watchlist>`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I combine results with Observable? Preferably not in Lamda notation.

Other resources I looked at:
- [android rxjava2/retrofit2 chaining calls with pagination token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509728/android-rxjava2-retrofit2-chaining-calls-with-pagination-token)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the Observable. You can use recursion but if you have  large number of pages your calling stack might overflow. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498293/rxjava-and-cursor-based-restful-pagination/41524537)

Something like

```
private Observable<WatchList> getWatchlistFromServerHelper(String sessionToken, String accountId, int startPage) {
    int index = startPage;
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> pagecontrol = BehaviorSubject.create(startPage);
    Observable<WatchList> ret = pageControl.asObservable()
                                           .concatMap(new Function<Integer,Observable<WatchList>>()
                                                     {
                                                       Observable<WatchList> apply(Integer page) {
                                                            mRestAPI.fetchWatchlistOnServer(sessionToken, accountId, page)
                                                                    .doOnNext(new Function<watchList -> 
                                                                            (watchList.getPage() == watchList.getTotalPages() ? 
                                                                             Observable.<WatchList>empty().doOnCompleted(()->pageControl.onCompleted()) :
                                                                             pageControl.onNext(page+1)));
                                                        }
                                                     }
                                                     );
    return ret;
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

My below sample code is working, here you need to make some modifications according to your requirements.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull;
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Function;
import io.reactivex.processors.PublishProcessor;

/**
* Created by Akash on 11/11/17.
*/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int VISIBLE_THRESHOLD = 1;
@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.progressBar)
ProgressBar progressBar;


private CompositeDisposable mDisposable;
private PublishProcessor<Integer> mPaginator;
private RxPagingAdapter mAdapter;
private boolean isLoading = false;
private int pageNumber = 1;
private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    mPaginator = PublishProcessor.create();
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RxPagingAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // register scroll listener
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                               int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            lastVisibleItem = mLayoutManager
                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (!isLoading
                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + VISIBLE_THRESHOLD)) {
                pageNumber++;
                mPaginator.onNext(pageNumber);
                isLoading = true;
            }
        }
    });
    subscribeApi();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (!mDisposable.isDisposed())
        mDisposable.dispose();
}

/**
 * Adding to disposable.
 */
private void subscribeApi() {

    mDisposable.add(mPaginator
            .onBackpressureDrop()
            .concatMap(new Function<Integer, Publisher<List<String>>>() {
                @Override
                public Publisher<List<String>> apply(@NonNull Integer page) throws Exception {
                    isLoading = true;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return apiResponse(page);
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull List<String> items) throws Exception {
                    mAdapter.addItems(items);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    isLoading = false;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }));

    mPaginator.onNext(pageNumber);

}

/**
 * This is just sample.
 * You can call api with retrofit interface method which returns Flowable and there you go.
 */
private Flowable<List<String>> apiResponse(final int page) {
    return Flowable.just(true)
            .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(new Function<Boolean, List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String> apply(@NonNull Boolean value) throws Exception {
                    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        items.add("Item " + (page * 10 + i));
                    }
                    return items;
                }
            });
}
}
```

> Adapter class method

```
 void addItems(List<String> items) {
    this.itemArrayList.addAll(items);
 }
```

[Source : GitHub](https://github.com/Aks-4125/RxPagination)